# Can we calculate the standard deviation of a large number of average data?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, volatility

I am calculating the Value at Risk (VaR Formula=Deposits Initial balance * Volatility of deposits (standard deviation of returns of the deposits) * Critical Value of a probability distribution * Square root of time) of a data on the deposits in a bank and the volatilities through the standard deviation are the following:

Daily volatility (average) 2016: 7% (Annualized 108 %)
Daily volatility (average) 2017: 73 % (Annualized 1163 %)
Daily volatility (average) 2018: 5% (Annualized 81 %)
Daily volatility (average) 2019: 10 % (Annualized 163 %)
Daily volatility (average) 2020: 9% (Annualized 142 %)
Daily volatility (average) 2021: 13 % (Annualized 210 %)

To reduce the VaR, we calculate the standard deviation of the logarithm of deposit returns. I was wondering if that could be done?

It did reduce my VAR but I'm not very sure, if you can average the logarithm of the returns of the deposits.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What is your goal in getting a smaller number for standard deviation? After all, you can (physically) report whatever number you want, including one you picked because it's your birthday.

Comment: My objective is to obtain a Value at Risk value that is less than the last data of the data that I am analyzing. With a high value of the standard deviation, the value of the value at risk gives me above the last data of the data to be analyzed

Would that make sense?

That the maximum expected loss is greater